# How do I to test ngIf in cypress?

Tags: angular, cypress

I have the code

```
<div class="project" *ngIf="role$ | async">
    <button mat-button *ngIf="id !== 5" (click)="doSomething()">DO</button>
</div>
```

I am not sure `*ngIf` would invoke what attribute? `display` or `visible` or `disabled`? How do I to test it?

```
The following is the wrong code, I guess

cy.get('.project').then(($div) => {
     if ($div.is(':disabled')) {
     cy.log('Div is disabled!')
     return
  } else {
      cy.log('Div is enabled!')
     cy.wrap($div).click()
  }
 })
```

Comment: can you run this command and tell me what is logged?`cy.get('.project').invoke('attr', '*ngIf').then((val) => {cy.log(val)})`

Comment: If this doesn't work try using `ngIf` without the star.

Comment: It seems `*ngIf` can be invoked without error. Can I mock it as true or false?

Comment: What is the logged value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the existence of `div.project`, so a test would ideally know the value of the variable `role$`

```js
if (role$) {

  cy.get('div.project').should('not.exist')

} else {

  cy.get(`div.project`)
    .should('exist')
    .within(() => {

      // work on button
      if (id === 5) {
        cy.contains('button', 'DO').should('not.exist')
      } else {
        cy.contains('button', 'DO').click()
      }
    })
}
```

That's as much as I can tell you from the fragment of HTML.

Obviously you want to test the page based on features working or not working, so would need to know more about the app to improve the test.

Comment: You should not use if-statements in Cypress, this is a bad practice.

Comment: Cypress tells us we can use Javascript inside tests. So using if-statements is perfectly fine, I think you are just confused about conditional testing, which is something else entirely. @Oushma

Comment: Perhaps you were confused by a typo - the word if should be of as in ***a test would ideally know the value of the variable `role$`***. This means the test is deterministic (not conditional).

Answer (score 0):

In case you get true or false in the logs you can apply an assertion like this:

```js
cy.get('.project').should('have.attr', '*ngIf', 'true') //for true
cy.get('.project').should('have.attr', '*ngIf', 'false') //for false
```

Comment: I am not strong on cypress. If the div is not in the root, how can I get the element?

Comment: You can get an element using its inner text value like `cy.contains('element text')`. With your above example `cy.contains('DO')`.